# Get User Events in Box Windows SDK V2

Tags: box-api, box

I am looking to get user events in BOX Windows SDK v2. However, it seems that /events endpoint is not implemented in BOX Windows SDK v2.

Here is the box api page: https://developers.box.com/docs/#events-get-events-for-a-user
I am using this SDK: https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2
But, it seems this SDK does not have implementation for the above /events endpoint.

Pls guide me in right direction, Do I need to write custom implementation to get user events ?
I am a beginner in DotNet. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the `events` endpoint has not been implemented in the Box Windows SDK. Perhaps the easiest (though not *easy*) thing to do is to [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) the existing SDK repo and add that support yourself. You'll want to create a new `EventsManager` class that contains this functionality. Consider using an existing manager class (such as the [FoldersManager](https://github.com/box/box-windows-sdk-v2/blob/master/Box.V2/Managers/BoxFoldersManager.cs)) as a basis for your work.